# How to prove that reflexivity, symmetry and transitivity are logically independent

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I need to build a proof for the following sentences

$φ_1=∀_xp(x,x)$

$φ_2=∀_x∀_y(p(x,y) \rightarrow p(y, x))$

$φ_3=∀_x∀_y∀_z(p(x,y)\land p(y,z) \rightarrow p(x, z))$

which express the reflexivity, symmetry, and transitivity of the predicate p.

I need to show that none of these sentences is a logical consequence of the other two by choosing, for each pair of sentences, an interpretation that satisfies two sentences from them, but does not satisfy the third one.

Essentially I am requested to find three binary relations where each one satisfies just two of these properties.

I can find several proofs on the web why symmetry and transitivity do not imply reflexivity.
However, I can not find those solutions for the other two cases as requested in this exercise:

- symmetry and reflexivity
- transitivity and reflexivity

So I am trying to build a proof for such exercise as follows:

Considering the domain D={a,b,c}

Symmetry and Reflexivity:

$m_1 (p)=\{(a,a),(b,b),(c,c),(a,b),(b,a),(b,c),(c,b)\}$

Symmetry and Transitivity :

$m_2 (p)=\{(a,b),(b,a),(b,c),(c,b),(a,c),(c,a)\}$

Transitivity ansd Reflexivity:

$m_3 (p)=\{(a,a),(b,b),(c,c),(a,b),(b,c)\}$

However, they clearly do not attend those rules $\forall$x, $\forall$y, and $\forall$z.
How can I accomplish that?

Comment: $m_1:~p(a,b)$ and $p(b,c)$ but not $p(a,c)$, so this is indeed nontransitive (and reflexive and symmetric). $m_3:~$ Try removing $(b,c)$ and it should be transitive and reflexive, but not symmetric.

Comment: Do you mean that? $m_3=\{(a,a),(b,b),(c,c),(a,b)\}$

But what about if I get (b, b) -> (c, c)? I would then need (b, c), not?

Comment: You would need (b,c) only if you already had (b, x) and (x, c). You don't have any x like that here (in the new $m_3$)

Comment: Could you please write an answer explaining to me your answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$m_1$ and $m_2$ seem alright. $m_3$ is almost there $-$ if you get rid of $(b,c)$, then it becomes transitive and reflexive but not symmetric. It is easy to see that the presence of $(a,b)$ and the absence of $(b,a)$ breaks symmetry, while the inclusion of $(a,a),(b,b),(c,c)$ ensures reflexivity. Why is it transitive though? Recall what it means to be transitive: if we have both $(x,y)$ and $(y,z)$, then we must necessarily have $(x,z)$ as well. Let's see if that works here.

$x=a:$ we have $(a,a)$, so let $y=a$. What are all the possible $z$s, i.e. stuff that $y=a$ is related to? Since the only pairs starting with $a$ are $(a,a),(a,b)$, so only choices for $z$ are $a,b$. Let us check if $(x,z)$ holds for either $z$. We find that indeed, $(a,a)$ and $(a,b)$ hold, so all good.

But we also have $(a,b)$, so now let's let $y=b$. Then what could $z$ be? The only pair starting with $b$ is $(b,b)$, so the only possible value of $z$ is $b$. Let's see if $(x,z)=(a,b)$ holds... it does!

$x=b:$ we have $(b,b)$, so $y$ can only be $b$, but as discussed earlier, $z$ can only be $b$ too, so we only have to check if $(x,z)=(b,b)$ exists, which it indeed does.

Similarly for $x=c$.

It looks really long when I describe it like this, but once you get the hang of it you'll be able to 'spot it' right away.

Comment: Thanks, @RaadShaikh, But let me ask you something, ok?
What about the rules  ∀x, ∀y, and ∀z?

Comment: That is not something we do need to care about?

Comment: @Breno "*what about the rules $\forall x,\forall y, \forall z$*"  What about them?  What doubts do you still have?  The relation Raad gives here is indeed transitive.  Further, the much smaller relation $\{(a,b)\}$ is also transitive.  Can you see why?  Do not make the mistake of thinking that to be transitive we require the existence of pairs $(x,y)$ and $(y,z)$ in the first place... transitivity just says that **if** those pairs both happened to exist then so too must $(x,z)$ exist.  Further, do not make the mistake of assuming that $x,y,z$ must all be distinct.  Some of these may be equal.

Comment: I am sorry,@JMoravitzGenericName I am just a beginner. For me it should mean that for every value in the domain the transitivity should hold...

Comment: Can you point out an example of a relation/value you feel was not covered or missed out?

Comment: It just seems to me a little awkward that $\{(a,a),(b,b),(c,c),(a,b)\}$ is true while it cannot be for any other value like $(b,c)$ or $(a,c)$

Comment: You can replace $(a,b)$ with $(b,c)$ or with $(a,c)$ and it should still work.

Comment: Hey, @RaadShaikh, I kind of understood what you mean by now...
So please answert only one more thing ok?
$m_3$ could also be the set $\{(a,a),(b,b),(c,c),(a,b),(b,c),(a,c) \}$, right?

Comment: Yes, that should work too!